# Angular 14: App not routing even though path changes in the URL

Tags: angular, angular14

I am setting up a basic angular website and my routing does not appear to be working.

I have a app.component.html page (acting currently as my Home page):

```
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" [routerLink] = "['']">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" [routerLink] = "['login']" >Login</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" [routerLink] = "['register']" routerLinkActive = "active" >Register</a>
        </li>
```

I then have a login and register component, very basic:

Login

and

Register

They are both included in my authModule:

```
import {NgModule} from "@angular/core";
import {CommonModule} from "@angular/common";
import {LoginComponent} from "../components/login/login.component";
import {RegisterComponent} from "../components/register/register.component";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    LoginComponent,
    RegisterComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  exports : [
    LoginComponent,
    RegisterComponent
  ]
})
export class AuthModule { }
```

Then this is my app.module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import {AuthModule} from "./auth/auth/auth.module";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    AuthModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

and finally my app-routing.module:

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {RouterModule, Routes} from '@angular/router';
import {LoginComponent} from "./auth/components/login/login.component";
import {RegisterComponent} from "./auth/components/register/register.component";
import {AppComponent} from "./app.component";

const routes: Routes = [
  {path: "", component: AppComponent, pathMatch: 'full'},
  {path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
  {path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent},
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {
}
```

When the app loads, it shows
http://localhost:4200/ and correctly show my home page.

But when I click the Login button the url changes to:

```
http://localhost:4200/login
```

but does not change the content on the page.

I am wondering if anyone can help.

Thank You :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` on the root page? I think you are missing this.

You can read more about it here: https://angular.io/api/router/RouterOutlet

Answer (score -1):

```
    <li class="nav-item active">
      <a class="nav-link" [routerLink] = "'/'">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" [routerLink] = "'/login'" >Login</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" [routerLink] = "'/register'" routerLinkActive = "active" >Register</a>
    </li>
```